# Isomorphism between two groups of order $p^6$

Tags: group-theory

Let $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ denote the finite field of order $p^n$. Let $G$ be the group 
$$ \begin{Bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & a & b\\ 0 & 1 & c\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\colon a,b,c\in\mathbb{F}_{p^2}
\end{Bmatrix}
$$ 
and $H$ be the group 
$$ \begin{Bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & a & b\\ 0 & 1 & c\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\colon a,b,c\in\mathbb{F}_{p}
\end{Bmatrix}.
$$

**Question:** Is it true that $G$ is isomorphic to $H\times H$ (external direct product)?

[The group $G$ appears in a paper of Burnside while talking about automorphisms preserving conjugacy classes. To understand the automorphism group of $G$, I tried to check whether $G$ and $H\times H$ are isomorphic?]

Comment: For $p>2$, in $H\times H$ there are no elements of order $p^2$, but are there any in $G$?

Comment: For $p$ odd,  both groups have exponent $p$.  I am sure that they are not isomorphic (I checked by computer for $p=2,3,5$), but I haven't thought of a proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This involves a bit of calculation, but one way to show that these groups are not isomorphic is to show that all non-central elements of $G$ (i.e. those with $a \ne 0$ or $c \ne 0$) have centralizers of order $p^4$ and conjugacy class of sixe $p^2$. Any such $g$ is conjugate to $gz$ for all $z \in Z(G)$.

However, the non-central elements in the direct factors of $H \times H$ have centralizers of order $p^5$ and conjugacy class of size $p$.